# Weka Correctly classified instances not showing

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Im using bike sharing dataset: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bike+Sharing+Dataset
And trying to find the accuracy in Weka
and I picked "holiday" as label and changed it's data type to nominal but Correctly classified instances is not showing at all.
What to do?
[image: only shows correlation coef][image: Selected attribute (holiday (label))]

...............................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Weka only outputs `Correlation coefficient` if the class is numeric.

Please note, that Weka will select the **last** attribute as **class** attribute by default in its Explorer tabs. If the `holiday` attribute is not the last attribute, make sure to select it on the *Classify* tab from the combobox above the *Start* button before building your classifier (selecting the class attribute in the *Preprocess* has no impact on the other tabs!).